# Assembly: How to move back to the input?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
String Enter Num:

  mov ah,01   
  int 21h

//must only accept 0-9
```

How can i make the cursor go back after the string if the user inputs backspace and enter?

Comment: What is your intended user experience? Read in any characters enabling backspace and enter, and then validate that input it only (ascii) '0'-'9'? Or read in one '0'-'9' character at a time, ignoring other chars? If the former, you may want to look at [`INT 21/AH=0AH`](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a) which will read stdin/console interactive data into a buffer, letting DOS handle the "hard work" of backspace, checking for enter and break, etc.

Answer (score 1):

DOS function [Int 21/AH=01h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm) doesn't care which key the user pressed,
it just returns the character in AL.

```
Key         AL

0           48
Backspace    8
Enter       13
```

However, as you chose the function which **echoes** enterred characters, they are interpreted by the terminal:
Ordinary characters are displayed and cursor advanced.
Backspace returns cursor one position back.
Enter makes new line.

If you don't like this behaviour, use **nonechoing** function [Int 21/AH=07h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2560.htm) instead,
or use BIOS keyboard function [Int 16/AH=00h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm).